# Send image data to web page from app

Tags: javascript, php, ios, ajax

I am creating an application which requires an image to be sent to a web service to be their profile picture though I have found that you can't directly send the base64 code via the url as it makes the url too big and I was wondering if there was a way to do it other than using the url bar. This data needs to be on the site before it loads so that the php can do its work and create a file for it before adding the data to the database.

I was wondering if you could inject the image via javascript on the device and then catch that javascript to use via a function which would use ajax to post the data to another php page

I am open to any suggestions of what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can send image to server as multipart-data,see the below code:Hope it helps

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url_string]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request1 setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSData *imageData = image;
NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request1 addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_profile[image_attributes][attachment]\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request1 setHTTPBody:body];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

Comment: How would I access the in my php file

Comment: the image send from iphone will be saved in the server with the filename as specified(photo.jpg)in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you point out that you are using a webservice i don't see the need of the picture being transmitted via the URL. If you are using SOAP for example you can embed the base64 string into your XML envelope and send it.

This is some code i've used in a project to send a base64 encoded string to a webservice.

```
 // build up base64 encode string from image
NSString* image = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0f) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

// the call
NSString* envelopeText = CREATE_ENVELOPE_HERE

NSData *envelope = [envelopeText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// construct request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webServiceUrl]];

[request addValue:@"SOAP_ACTION_HERE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:envelope];
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [envelope length]]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// fire away
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) {
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NSURLConnection initWithRequest: Failed to return a connection.");
}
```

Furthermore i must say that i don't understand the last part of your question correctly. You want to upload the picture via an iOS app and then load a page which uses it?

Comment: How would I access the in my php file